# Xtext Scope and Name provider

Tags: xtext

How do you integrate a scope provider and a custom name for a grammar rule?

The grammar

```
Model:
    g+=Greeting+
    (vis+=Visible)*
    ref=Ref;
Ref:
    'ref_greeting' grt=[Greeting];
Visible:
     'vis' make=[Greeting]; 
Greeting:
    'Hallo' name=ID '!';
```

The rule `Visible` is used to define `Greeting` that are visible from other, for the scope of the rule `Ref`. The two input files are:

```
Hallo hallo!
Hallo hallo_other_vis!
ref_greeting hallo
```

and

```
Hallo h!
vis hallo_other_vis
ref_greeting hallo_other_vis   <--- error here
```

For the scope of the second file `h` is visible but not `hallo_other_vis` which must be visible for the desired results.

The scope provider is:

```
override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
    if(context instanceof Ref && reference == MyDslPackage.Literals.REF__GRT){
        var root =  EcoreUtil2.getContainerOfType(context, Model)
        var scope = Scopes.scopeFor(root.g)
        if(root.vis !== null){
            return Scopes.scopeFor(root.vis, scope) /// XXX is this correct
        }
    }
    return super.getScope(context, reference)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you scope greetings you have to collect greetings

```
return Scopes.scopeFor(root.vis, scope)
```

collects `Visible`s and not `Greetings`
so you should fix that e.g.

```
return Scopes.scopeFor(root.vis.map[make], scope)
```

Comment: In my larger program I get the error `ERROR org.eclipse.xtext.linking.lazy.LazyLinkingResource  - Cyclic resolution of lazy links : Visible.make->Visible.make`  and the execption `LazyLinkingResource$CyclicLinkingException`. The example of this question does work now.